# using target in css to keep color

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have the following example in http://jsfiddle.net/uA97K/

What I am trying to achieve is to keep the same colour on a selected tab as the hover. So when a user clicks on a tab, that selected tab will remain blue until another tab is selected.

I thought this could be done by using a:target but does look to be working.

```
#bar a:target { background: #00A3EF; color: #003366;}
```

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Hm, this is a little difficult. `:target` only applies to the element with the target ID, not the element with a link to that target. I'm not aware of a selector that would apply to the latter (which in this case is the selected tab).

Comment: why dont you change the color on click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only CSS, you can't do it. But you can use jQuery, and an .active class for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/uA97K/1/

```
$('#bar a').click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is, as already noted, impossible with CSS currently. It is, however, possible with plain JavaScript (albeit the following demonstration works only with browsers that support `document.querySelector()`, `addEventListener()` and the `element.classList` API):

```
function hashMonitor() {
    var D = document,
        active = D.querySelector('a.active'),
        link = D.querySelector('[href="#' + D.querySelector(':target').id + '"]');
    if (active) {
        active.classList.remove('active');
    }
    link.classList.add('active');
}
window.addEventListener('hashchange', hashMonitor, false);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uA97K/3/).

Conceivably, under Level 4 of CSS (currently *entirely* unsupported in the wild) this *could* become possible, but until implementations appear it seems fruitless to speculate on *how* such selectors might be used.

References:

- [CSS Selectors, Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#idref-combinators).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).
- [`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.classList).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).